# Selecting and setting value of the previous element of a last element

Tags: jquery

I have following list of text boxes added dynamically

```
<tr class="dimensionStone">
<td><input type="text" name="todayDimensionStones[].stoneNo" id="stoneNo" value=0 onclick="keyPressListener1(this.id)" onfocus="keyPressListener1(this.id)" Class="controlStock"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="todayDimensionStones[].length" id="length" value=0 onchange="findDimension(this.id)" onclick="keyPressListener(this.id)" onfocus="keyPressListener(this.id)" Class="controlStock"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="todayDimensionStones[].breadth" id="breadth" value=0 onchange="findDimension(this.id)" onclick="keyPressListener(this.id)" onfocus="keyPressListener(this.id)" Class="controlStock"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="todayDimensionStones[].height" id="height" value=0 onchange="findDimension(this.id)" onclick="keyPressListener(this.id)" onfocus="keyPressListener(this.id)" Class="controlStock"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="todayDimensionStones[].dimension" id="dimension" value=0 onchange="findDimension(this.id)" onclick="keyDownDisableListener(this.id)" Class="controlStock"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="todayDimensionStones[].isIssued" id="isIssued" value="No" onfocus="keyDownDisableListener(this.id)" Class="controlStock"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="todayDimensionStones[].status" id="status" onfocus="keyDownDisableListener(this.id)" Class="controlStock"/></td>   
<td><a href="#" class="removeDimensionStone"><img src="images/1minus.png" width="20" height="20" title="Remove Dimension Stone"/></a></td>
</tr>
```

I have been using following jquery to set the value of first 5 elements to zero and last element to no value

```
$(rowElement).find("input").val(0);
$(rowElement).find(":text:last").val('');
```

But I cannot find jquery to reset the value of previous element of last element.I have searched more.Please help me

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/prev/ is how you get the previous element, but in your case why not use `$('#status')`?

Comment: But I have used this as $(rowElement).find(":text:last").prev().val("No") and $(rowElement).find(":text:last").prev().find('input').val("No") but both are not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var rowElement = $('.dimensionStone')
var el = $(rowElement).find("input");

el.val(0).last().val('').eq(el.length-2).val('test');
// ^^ all         ^^ last                ^^ second last
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5wpkw/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(rowElement).find(":text:nth-last-child(2)").val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

To reset the value of previous element of last element :

```
$(rowElement).find(":text:last").prev(":text").val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
//will set each input text to 0
$("#txtDiv").find("input").val(0);

//will set last input text to ""
$("#txtDiv").find("input").last().val("");

//will change text of all previous text fields before last
$("#txtDiv").find("input").last().prevAll().val("Hello");
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zpVaL/

i hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$('input:text').val(0).last().val('').prev().val('test');
```